# Use Pivot Table to Fetch Data from Main Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using two tables and a pivot table

Table 1 named `calendars`.

Table 2 named `calendar_groups`.

Pivot table `calendar_calendar_group`.

I'm trying to get data from Table 1 based on a where value in the pivot table. Where `calendar_groups_id = 1` then use `calendar_id` to get data from table 1. I can't get it to work.

```php
$event = new Calendar();
$event->orderBy('start', 'asc')
    ->whereHas('calendar_groups', function ($q) {
        $q->wherePivot('calendar_groups_id', '=', '1');
    })->with('calendar_groups')
    ->first();
```

This gives me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in
>   'where clause'

This is the relationship:

```
public function calendar_groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CalendarGroup::class);
    }
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Post your `Calendar` model or at least the relation definition.

Comment: Try just `$q->where('id', '=', '1');` assuming pimary key in `calendar_groups` is `id`.

Comment: @brnd0 I added the relationship from my calendar model

Answer (score 0):

I think @Tpojka is right here. If you're trying to get Calendar instances that belong to desired CalendarGroup then replace the code should look like this:

```
$event = new Calendar();
$group = 1;
$event->orderBy('start', 'asc')
    ->whereHas('calendar_groups', function ($q) use ($group) {
        //$q->wherePivot('calendar_groups_id', '=', $group);
        $q->where('id', '=', $group);
    })->with('calendar_groups')
    ->first();
```

If I'm reading the documentation correctly `wherePivot()` should be used like this:

```
$event = new Calendar();
$event->calendar_groups()->wherePivot('some_pivot_column',1)->get();
```

But this would return you the `CalendarGroup` instances.

If you'd want to do it through Eloquent but without going all the way to the `CalendarGroup` then you'd probably need to create a Model (let's call it `CalendarCalendarGroupPivot`) for the pivot table and add another relation (`hasMany('CalendarCalendarGroupPivot')`) to your `Calendar` model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got it working.

I used your suggestions but still don't understand a little part of it.
When I use the suggestions made:

```
$event = new Calendar;
                $event->orderBy('start', 'asc')
            ->whereHas('calendar_groups', function($q) {
                    $q->where('calendar_group_id', '=', '1');
                })->with('calendar_groups')

            ->first();
```

I get an empty collection.

But if I run this:

```
$event = Calendar::orderBy('start', 'asc')
        ->whereHas('calendar_groups', function($q) {
                $q->where('calendar_group_id', '=', '1');
            })->with('calendar_groups')

        ->first();
```

I get the desired results

Can anybody tell me the difference between so I can learn from it?